# CATransform3D Key Paths with #keyPath

Tags: swift3, transform, scale, cabasicanimation, catransform3d

Is it possible to use enhanced key path (as described [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Key-ValueCodingExtensions/Key-ValueCodingExtensions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004514-CH12-SW1)) for a CATransform3D property in Swift 3 with new #keyPath keyword?

In other words to replace

```
let scaleAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.scale")
```

with something like

```
let scaleAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath:  #keyPath(CALayer.transform.???))
```

Answer (score 18):

CAValueFunction should be used.

```
let scaleAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.scale")
```

->

```
let scaleAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: #keyPath(CALayer.transform))
scaleAnimation.valueFunction = CAValueFunction(name: kCAValueFunctionScale)
```

and

```
let rotationAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.rotation")
```

->

```
let rotationAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: #keyPath(CALayer.transform))
rotationAnimation.valueFunction = CAValueFunction(name: kCAValueFunctionRotateZ)
```

etc.

- `rotation.x` -> `kCAValueFunctionRotateX`
- `rotation.y` -> `kCAValueFunctionRotateY`
- `rotation.z` -> `kCAValueFunctionRotateZ`
- `rotation` -> `kCAValueFunctionRotateZ`
- `scale.x` -> `kCAValueFunctionScaleX`
- `scale.y` -> `kCAValueFunctionScaleY`
- `scale.z` -> `kCAValueFunctionScaleZ`
- `scale` -> `kCAValueFunctionScale`
- `translation.x` -> `kCAValueFunctionTranslateX`
- `translation.y` -> `kCAValueFunctionTranslateY`
- `translation.z` -> `kCAValueFunctionTranslateZ`
- `translation` -> `kCAValueFunctionTranslate`

Comment: you said it doesn't work well for you, but it seems to work great for me! I had a `CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.rotation")` and now I have this in Swift 4.2: `let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: #keyPath(CALayer.transform)); animation.valueFunction = CAValueFunction(name: CAValueFunctionName.rotateZ)`

Comment: @gobe It is quite a long time (almost 2 years). That's great news. I will update my comment. Thank you.

Comment: Hi. Any idea why this wouldn't work with `CASpringAnimation`? When I use `let animation = CASpringAnimation(keyPath: "transform.scale")`, it works fine, but if replaced with `let animation = CASpringAnimation(keyPath: #keyPath(CALayer.transform)); animation.valueFunction = CAValueFunction(name: CAValueFunctionName.scale)`, the animation simply doesn't run.